# woocommerce remove action based on product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

everyone, i am trying to stop a plugin function from executing if a certain product id is in the cart. I have tried and written the following code and put them in my theme functions.php, but it doesn't seem to work. Instead, the whole page become blank. Can anyone help me out?

```
$found = false;
global $woocommerce;
foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    if( $_product->id == 1097 ) {
        $found = true;
    }
}
if ($found){
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', array($wdt, 'show_field'), 20);
}
```

By itself, `remove_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', array($wdt, 'show_field'), 20);` works. But once i tried to link it to work base on product id, the whole website just cannot load. Thank you!

Comment: i suspected that i need to place them into a function. but once i did so, and execute the function by using `add_action ('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'function_name'); `. the remove action does not work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$wdt` does not seam to be initialized. You should ether use the class name(string) or an instance of that class here.

An other guess is that your code runs before the action is added. Make sure you run your code on a later hook in the execution see this for reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

So if the code that add the hook runs at `init`, you can try to run your code at `wp_loaded`. Like this:

```
add_action('wp_loaded','my_remove_order_notes');

function my_remove_order_notes()
{
    //Your code
}
```

Also, make sure that the priority parameter matches with the code where the action hook is added. The default priority is 10.

Edit:
Ok, you should not remove the filter. Filters are supposed to be used for manipulating the data and the return the new data back. Like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_remove_order_comments', 99 );

function custom_remove_order_comments( $fields )
{
    global $woocommerce;     
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {         
    $_product = $values['data'];         
    if( $_product->id == 1097 ) {   
        unset($fields['order']['order_comments']); //Remove the order comments field
    }
    return $fields; //Return the data back to WooCommerce
}
```

Comment: I see. noted. I have somehow got it to work. but i met with another problem. wondering if you could help me with it. You see, as i was doing the same thing to remove a filter using the code below, the whole checkout field dissappeared. i tried increase and decreasing the remove_filter priority, but still no use.

Comment: `function nn_remove_wdt3(){
    $found = false;
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if( $_product->id == 1097 ) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if ($found){
        global $wdt;
        remove_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', array($wdt, 'checkout_fields'), 999);
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'nn_remove_wdt3' );`

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind help, Pelmered. Unfortunately, the field that i am trying to remove is created by another plugin. and when i print out the $fields, the field that i am targetting is not inside. how do i proceed on from here?

Comment: That's probably because your code is running before the code in the plugin witch means that the field has not been added yet when your code runs. This can easily be solved by changing the priority for you hook, that's the third parameter in add_filter. See my edited post again.

Comment: Thank you! that solve the problem! However, i had to remove the `break;` statement before it works.